# RoboGuice 2.0 installation giving ClassNotFoundException with ADT and API 17

Tags: android, roboguice

I am trying to get myself up and running with RoboGuice 2 and I have added **guice-3.0-no_aop**, **roboguice-2.0** and **jsr305-1.3.9** jars into the projects classpath but I am getting following exception when I try the code given below:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1143): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 
ComponentInfo{com.wickedlynotsmart.myfirstapp/com.wickedlynotsmart.myfirstapp.acti
vity.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"com.wickedlynotsmart.myfirstapp.activity.MainActivity" on path: 
/data/app/com.wickedlynotsmart.myfirstapp-2.apk
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends RoboActivity {

    @InjectView(R.id.helloTextView)
    private TextView helloTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        helloTextView.setText("Hello, My First App!");
    }

    //...
```

}

**MyFirstAppModule.java**

```
public class MyFirstAppModule extends AbstractModule{

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

}
```

**roboguice.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="roboguice_modules">
        <item>com.wickedlynotsmart.myfirstapp.module.MyFirstAppModule</item>
    </string-array>    
</resources>
```

Could someone help me understand with it?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I am using Android API 17 with Android Development Tool.

Answer (score 1):

Removed `guice-3.0-no_aop`, `roboguice-2.0` and `jsr305-1.3.9` jars from project's build path.

Adding following jars to `libs` folder inside the project got the project working:

```
1. roboguice-2.0.jar
2. guice-3.0-no_aop.jar
3. javax.inject.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the ADT. I tried Roboguice on both ADT with Android Development Toolkit v22 and Eclipse JUNO with Android Development Toolkit v21.It worked in Eclipse JUNO with ADT v21.

In ADT i put the jar files to libs folder and i get `ClassNotFoundException`. 
In Eclipse JUNO, when i put the jar files to `libs` folder, it automatically creates and puts the jar files under Android Dependencies. This doesnt happen in ADT.

Adding jar files to build path didnt work either.

Comment: Adding `roboguice-2.0.jar`, `guice-3.0-no_aop.jar` and `javax.inject.jar` into the `libs` folder worked just fine for me for both ADT package 21 and 22.